# Anyone know what year this is from? Found under 100 year old building.

Tags: baseball

[image]

This schedule is on the side of a milk jug that is very old. If anyone knows a fast way to figure out what year this schedule took place just out of curiousity that would be cool.

Comment: The first night game at Fenway was in 1947. That at least gives you a start date.

Comment: And the old Washington Senators left for Texas in 1971. So your search region is now 1947-1970.  A pretty broad range.  Best I can do right now.

Comment: Of course these dates are not consistent with a 100 year old building.  The night games make this very intriguing because I can't find mention of night games in 1917 - a 100 years ago.  Earliest mention is around 1935 in Cincy.

Answer (score 5):

This was from [1963](http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/1963-schedule-scores.shtml), based on the schedule and the teams.  Thanks to @John for pointing out the range to search in (1947-1970, based on the first night game at Fenway, and the last year the Senators played in Washington).

Comment: Comments are meant to be transitory on Stack Exchange - it would be great if you could add the hints into your answer to put all the information in one place.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. 1963 sounds about right. The building was built in 1908 but it could have been swept under there anytime.

Comment: @Joe Good detective work!!